# Do Postgres and Oracle databases maintain insertion order?

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, data-structures

I am trying to store a collection (which preserves the order of its elements). I will iterate over the collection and will insert the elements one by one into the DB. Suppose I want to retrieve the elements one by one. Will I be able to retrieve the elements in the order I inserted them?

Comment: Rows in a relational database are **not** sorted. If you want to retrieve them in a defined order you need an `order by` and thus a column on which you can order by (e.g. the index from the collection, an autoincrement column or a timestamp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, database tables are heap oriented. So theoretically in a single writer mode, when all the rows were of equal size, then this *"could"* work. But when you leave some free space in some page and then later you insert shorter row it will be put into that page.

So please do not trust insertion order in any database. Including MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not. 
If you want to retrieve rows in an order, you should use a sequence ( like Id column, primary key ) and an order by clause regarding to this id column.

Oracle built in rowid pseudo column contains row number information  ; but you should not rely on this. Table may enabled row movement property.

Comment: `rowid` does **not** contain a "row number". It's the physical _address_ of the row in the tablespace.

Comment: You can check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm : The position of the row in the data block (first row is 0)